# If the constraints stop being met while the job is running, reschedule the job and show a Toast message saying that the job failed

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am playing with android JobService and in the process, I came along with the following challenge from **Google codelabs**:

**Challenge:** Up until now, your JobService tasks have simply delivered a notification, but JobScheduler is usually used for more robust background tasks, such as updating the weather or syncing with a database. Because background tasks can be more complex, programmatically and functionally, the job of notifying the framework when the task is complete falls on the developer. Fortunately, the developer can do this by calling jobFinished().

This challenge requires you to call jobFinished() after the task is complete:

- Implement a JobService that starts an AsyncTask when the given
  constraints are met.
- The AsyncTask should sleep for 5 seconds.
- If the    constraints stop being met while the thread is sleeping,
  reschedule    the job and show a Toast message saying that the job
  failed.

Well, I am struck at point number 3.

**How can I determine whether the job constraints are still being met while the job is running?**

Here is my code:

**SyncActivity.kt**

```
public fun scheduleSyncJob(view : View){
        val selectedNetworkID = networkOptionsSync.checkedRadioButtonId
        var selectedNetworkOption = JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE
        when (selectedNetworkID) {
            R.id.noNetworkSync -> selectedNetworkOption = JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE
            R.id.anyNetworkSync -> selectedNetworkOption = JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY
            R.id.wifiNetworkSync -> selectedNetworkOption = JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED
        }

        val serviceName = ComponentName(packageName, AsynctaskJobService::class.java.name)
        val builder = JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(selectedNetworkOption)
            .setRequiresCharging(chargingSwitchSync.isChecked())


        val constraintSet = ((selectedNetworkOption != JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE) || chargingSwitchSync.isChecked)
        if (constraintSet) {
            val myJobInfo = builder.build()
            mScheduler?.schedule(myJobInfo)
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.job_scheduled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_constraint_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am scheduling my job if, either any type of network connection is available or the device is charging.

And here is the **AsynctaskJobService.kt**

```
class AsynctaskJobService : JobService() {
    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStartJob(jobParameters: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        JobTask(this).execute(jobParameters)
        return true
    }


    private class JobTask(private val jobService: JobService) :
        AsyncTask<JobParameters?, Void?, JobParameters>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: JobParameters?): JobParameters? {
            Log.d("Asynctask Running", System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
            SystemClock.sleep(5000)
            Log.d("Asynctask Running", System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
            return params[0]
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(jobParameters: JobParameters) {
            jobService.jobFinished(jobParameters, false)
            Toast.makeText(jobService, "Task Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi.. Have you got any solution?

Comment: Nothing till now.if you got a solution then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this..

Main constraint for job is WIFI network only.
Whenever the constraint stop being met onStopJob callback method is called. hence i showed my message here.

You can try this.

Below is my job service(in java).

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    private MyBackgroundTask myBackgroundTask;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        myBackgroundTask = new MyBackgroundTask();
        Log.e("Test", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        myBackgroundTask.execute(params);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        if (myBackgroundTask != null) {
            myBackgroundTask.cancel(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job Interrupted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<JobParameters, Void, Boolean> {

        private JobParameters parameters;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(JobParameters... jobParameters) {
            try {
                parameters = jobParameters[0];
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if (aBoolean) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Job Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            jobFinished(parameters, !aBoolean);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.will try this within a day or two.will accept this answer if it works.